# Smearing out dataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

Say that I have a simple dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['3m',10, 12],['1y',12, 8.5],['2y',13, 4.6]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Term', '3m','1y'])
```

What is the easiest way to transform it into something like:

```
data = [['3m','3m', 10],['3m','1y', 12],['1y','3m', 12], ['1y','1y', 8.5], ['2y','3m', 13], ['2y','1y', 4.6]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Term', 'Term','metric'])
```

I need to do this for a dataframe with much more columns so I am looking for a simple hack to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: One-line solution without memory-intensive lambda/apply:

```
pd.DataFrame(df1.set_index('Term').unstack().swaplevel()).reset_index()


    Term    level_1 0
0   3m      3m      10.0
1   1y      3m      12.0
2   2y      3m      13.0
3   3m      1y      12.0
4   1y      1y      8.5
5   2y      1y      4.6
```

Here's a multistep solution using `itertools.product` to get the combinations of existing index and column values, and `df.apply(lambda)` to look the values up in the original `df`. I'm guessing there are more efficient ways:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product
data = [['3m',10, 12],['1y',12, 8.5],['2y',13, 4.6]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Term', '3m','1y'])


   Term 3m  1y
0   3m  10  12.0
1   1y  12  8.5
2   2y  13  4.6

df3=pd.DataFrame(list(product(df1['Term'].values,df1.columns[1:])), columns=['term1','term2'])

    term1   term2
0   3m      3m
1   3m      1y
2   1y      3m
3   1y      1y
4   2y      3m
5   2y      1y

df3['metric']=df3.apply(lambda x:df1.set_index('Term').loc[x[0],x[1]], axis=1)

    term1   term2   metric
0   3m      3m      10.0
1   3m      1y      12.0
2   1y      3m      12.0
3   1y      1y      8.5
4   2y      3m      13.0
5   2y      1y      4.6
```

Comment: Editing with much simpler solution